# homestead can't access views

Tags: php, laravel, virtual-machine, homestead

I have this issue with homestead where it can't access any of my views instead it tells me NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145: (this is a new project) . When I try accessing an old laravel project which I made it works perfectly fine but when I create a new project it throws me this error. Now I have also tested it with php artisan serve and try accessing this on localhost:8000 and this works without problems. so why does homestead have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotFoundHttpException` is actually thrown when there was no matching route found.

Seeing how it's working fine using `artisan serve` I think you should have a look wether the 'app' is setup properly in the Homestead configuration.

You can find more info on that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#adding-additional-sites

Comment: thanks the problem actually was I had to run provision after this it would say welcome view not found so I decided to empty my cache using php artisan config:clear and it works now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In blade use `url()` funtion to route 
for example
 `<a href='login'>test</a>` 
to
`<a href='{{url("login")}}'>test</a>`
And make sure that `mod_rewrite` in enable